# The iterator is supposed to read an entire number, but it only reads the first digit

Tags: c++

I've written this code to extract numbers from a string using a string iterator.
The iterator picks up the first number and decides to call it a day. 
Why's it so?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 string myAge = "I am 23 years old";
 string::iterator iterator;
 char numberInCharacterForm;
 string numberInStringForm;
 stringstream convertToString;
 for(iterator = myAge.begin();iterator!=myAge.end();iterator++)
 {
              numberInCharacterForm = *iterator;
              if(numberInCharacterForm >= '0' & numberInCharacterForm <='9')
              {
               convertToString << numberInCharacterForm;
               convertToString >> numberInStringForm;
              }
 } 
 cout << numberInStringForm <<endl;   
 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

Output is 2;

Comment: You'll be wanting an '&&' in line 16 instead of a '&', BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just collect the characters into the `stringstream` and print it afterwards:

```
for(iterator = myAge.begin();iterator!=myAge.end();iterator++)
{
    numberInCharacterForm = *iterator;
    if(numberInCharacterForm >= '0' && numberInCharacterForm <='9') {
       // note: && instead of & here ^
       convertToString << numberInCharacterForm;
    }
 }   
 cout << convertToString.str() <<endl;
```

However there is no need for manual iteration over the string:

```
string myAge = "I am 23 years old"; 
string numberInStringForm;
std::remove_copy_if(myAge.begin(), myAge.end(), 
                    std::back_inserter(numberInStringForm),
                    std::not1(std::ptr_fun(isdigit)));
std::cout << numberInStringForm << std::endl;
```

Comment: Just collect the characters into the stringstream and print it afterwards: <- yeah i did that shortly after posting this question.

Your answer is brilliant! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use your `stringstream convertToString`.  And your not quite using it right, so that's where your problem is sneaking in.  Since we're just dealing with characters, and no actual numbers, you can just keep it all as strings:

```
int main()
{
  std::string myAge = "I am 23 years old";
  std::ostringstream digits;

  for(std::string::const_iterator iterator = myAge.begin();
      iterator != myAge.end();
      ++iterator)
  {
      const char numberInCharacterForm = *iterator;
      if(isdigit(numberInCharacterForm))
      {
         digits << numberInCharacterForm;
      }
  }

  std::cout << digits.str() <<endl;   
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

References:

- [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/)
- [ostringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/)